# How to modify MemberBinding expression using Expression Visitor

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-expressions, expressionvisitor

I am trying to modify MemberBinding expression using Expression visitor. But I am getting an error when I try to compile the modified expression which says:

**'variable 'source' of type 'EFTest.Views.TestView' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'**

I would also like to mention that i do not get any error if I return MemberBinding as it is in VisitMemberBinding function. I have also made sure that the modified Expression is exactly same as the orignal one.

*Final purpose of this work will be to block a specific column in all linq queries in EntityFramework Core. Please let me know if you have suggestions regarding that.*

Sample codes are below

```
class Expre
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataContext context = new DataContext();

        var rs = context.Query<TestView>().Select(m => new MyModel()
        {
            Id = m.DocumentId,
        });

        Visitor visitor = new Visitor();
        var ss = visitor.Modify(rs.Expression);
        var CompiledLambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(ss).Compile();

        EntityQueryable<MyModel> queryAble = (EntityQueryable<MyModel>)CompiledLambdaExpression.DynamicInvoke();
        var rss = Enumerable.ToList(queryAble);

    }
}

public class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public MemberBinding MemberBinding;
    public Expression Modify(Expression expression)
    {
        var r = Visit(expression);
        return r;
    }

    protected override MemberBinding VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
    {
        Type targetType = typeof(MyModel);
        Type sourceType = typeof(TestView);

        PropertyInfo SourceProperty = sourceType.GetProperty("DocumentId");
        PropertyInfo TargetProperty = targetType.GetProperty("Id");

        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, "m");

        MemberExpression propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, SourceProperty);
        MemberBinding memberBinding = Expression.Bind(TargetProperty, propertyExpression);

        return base.VisitMemberBinding(memberBinding);
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
public class MyModel
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class TestView 
{
    public Int32 Code { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public Int32 DocumentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Modifying expression trees is a complex task and usually involves overriding more than one `VisitXyz` methods. You cannot just create parameters on the fly. Regarding your final goal, it cannot be seen from the example. Are you trying to replace the `Select`? Consider providing more realistic example of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to replace BindingExpressions inside Select. that is the goal for this example. Regarding my final goal I am asking for suggestions only. If I wouldn't mention that I am sure someone would ask what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: No offense here. The problem is that the code you've posted makes no sense. You are trying to replace `Id = m.DocumentId` with another `Id = m.DocumentId` where second `m` is a **different** parameter than the original lambda parameter `m` (the names are the same, but instances are different), that's why you are getting the exception. Member binding has two parts - destination and source, not sure which one are you trying to replace in order to give you a solution. `MemberBinding` is part of `MemberInit` which is part of `LambdaExpression` which holds the original `m` parameter.

Comment: I have figured it out. As you said it is because of different instances. I used the lambda parameter from original expression to modify it according to my requirements. By the way its kind of a pre-work and I was trying to find a way to modify the expressions. thanks by the way.